# I want to open my page Language Specific NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

[image: My webpage (Currently)]

I am using NextJs and ui18n to make it international my webpage. My page starts with en-US on my language combobox, first time when I open my page it's open like in the picture.

```
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
    localeDetection: true
```

I also have these specification on my nextconfig.js file.
When I select another language it changes correctly like "http://localhost:3000/en-AU" yet if re-select en-US it turns back to "localhost:3000/" again.
How can I make my url "localhost:3000/en-US" at start or after I reselect en-US option

Answer (score 0):

I set my default language something else.

```
default-language= "id-ID"
```

I don't know, how exactly it work but it works for me.